# NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, console

I'm following through the Ruby on Rails tutorial, and when attempting to save a user in Rails Console (sandbox mode), I get the following error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
from (irb):7
```

Note: I typed in `User.new`, input a name and email, then `user.save`, and got the error above.

**Full code:**

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rake db:migrate
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0020s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0020s) ===========================================


C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>rails console --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.0.1)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
irb(main):001:0> User.new
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
<ame: "Andrew Ghobrial", email: "email@gmail.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Andrew Ghobrial", email: "email@gmail.com",
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> user.save
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
        from (irb):4
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0> user.save
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
        from (irb):6
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
irb(main):007:0> user
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
        from (irb):7
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'`
```

Comment: post the code that gives this error

Comment: I typed in User.new, input a name and email, then input user.save, and got the error above.

Comment: you started with `user = User.new`, right?

Comment: I tried that, and it gave me the error:

 `'user' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Can you post every line you ran in IRB, exactly as you did it?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the description up top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as @Phlip said, your `User.new` isn't assigned to a variable.  If you do:

```
user = User.new(name: "Andrew Ghobrial", email: "email@gmail.com")

user.save
```

That will work, assuming your users table has `name` and `email` columns, and your user model looks something like:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email

end
```

Comment: That still gives me this error:

    `'user' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

However, in my user.rb file under the models folder, I have:

`class User < Activerecord::Base
 end`

Comment: Do you have fields defined in the `create_user` migration for `name` and `email`?  Those will need to be set on the `User` model.  See my edit.

Comment: Even after adding those fields, I'm still receiving that error. Even typing in `user` alone gives me that.

Comment: Have you closed and restarted the rails console?  In your app directory, do `rails c`

Comment: It could also have to do with running in `sandbox` mode in development...  You might want to try just straight development mode without `sandbox` (again, e.g. `rails c`)

Comment: Now when I input:

`user = User.new(name: "Andrew Ghobrial", email: "ghobrial.andrew@gmail.com")`

It gives me the error `syntax error, unexpected tLSHFT, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n'`

Pretty stumped myself.

Comment: I'm still not convinced your `app/models/user.rb` is correct.  Would you post that?

Comment: `class User << ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :name, :email

end`

Comment: Dumb question, but if it's all on one line like that, it'll need to be:  `class User << ActiveRecord::Base; attr_accessor :name, :email; end` - or did it just paste that way in the comment?  It might be mor helpful to add that to your question so others can see it as well.

Answer (score 1):

While the capitalisation answers haven't been upvoted, the very first line of the original post IRB proves this was the issue. My resource was created with a lowercase title:

```
rails g resource user
```

After the db migration:

Typing "user.count" in IRB gets the NameError

Typing "**U**ser.count" gets the expected result (for my empty table):

```
    irb(main):009:0> User.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user"
    => 0
```

So the IRB is case sensitive on active resources and seemingly must be capitalised in declarations. Typing "User" will return a list of the field/column names.

Answer (score 0):

1.9.3-p392 :004 > status.delete_all

in this  Status 's' needs to be capitalized to 'S'.

**or**

in this case

NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object

in this  Status 'u' needs to be capitalized to 'U'.

**or**

in this case

NameError: undefined local variable or method `post' for main:Object

in this  Status 'p' needs to be capitalized to 'P'.

Comment: This feels as though it's quite useful, but not for this question, which was verified as having a very different root cause than simple capitalization.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that in `(Resourse).user`, The first letter `(pin = Pin, or tweet = Tweet)` is capitalized.